# How can I make a multiple conditioned query on nosql

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How to make a no sql query for give query " if(   (is_new: false || from :'user1')  && participant : 'users1'" where participants is array which has two element participant:[ 0: user1, 1: user2 ]?

```
 is_new: true
participants: Array 0: 5e3536e1b29cf92840171f3e
                    1: 5e3537a9b29cf92840171f3f
fromUserId: 5e3537a9b29cf92840171f3f
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share the sample document and the required output.

Comment: bro i have shared the sample document in question  as a code.. and need a query as if the ******f3f is used as a search param in participants and fromuserid with is_new = false res shld be shown as this current docs bt if params are seached with ******f3e no res shld be found i was trying bt i dont know what is wrong in this -> { $and: [ { $or: [ { "is_new": false }, { "fromUserId": ObjectId("5e3536e1b29cf92840171f3e") } ] } ] , [ { "participants": { $elemMatch: {$eq: ObjectId("5e3536e1b29cf92840171f3e") } } } ] } ] }

Comment: If this answers your question please accept it so that we can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [{ is_new: false }, { fromUserId: "userId1" }],
  participants: { $in: ["userId1"] }
})
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KJe92_mCmdE)

> Note: replace `userId1` with your real _id

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there @vector, just a small change needs to be done

1. The bracket for `$and` is suppose to enclose both `$or` and the other `$elemMatch` query. For more about `$and` refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).
2. The `$elemMatch` syntax was not proper. For more about `$elemMatch` refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

Here I'm updating the query for you:

```
db.your_collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          is_new: false
        },
        {
          fromUserId: ObjectId("5e3536e1b29cf92840171f3e")
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      participants: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $eq: ObjectId("5e3536e1b29cf92840171f3e")
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thankyou very much Vijay Rajpurohit

Comment: hi vijay i need some more help.. Wht if i want to insert data in two different collections with  referencing one collection to other

Comment: Well for that you can ask a different question. Because we can't discuss that in comments.